# Is GroovyResourceLoader ever called outside the main ClassLoader?

Tags: groovy

Ive setup a GroovyResourceLoader and it seems to get requests for groovy scripts as necessary. I was just wondering is it specially used anywhere besides class loading ? Is there any benefit in simply wrapping a ClassLoader and loading *.groovy files there as opposed to using a GRL ? Are they just different ways to the same end ?

Answer (score 0):

GroovyResourceLoader (GRL) is used by GroovyClassLoader (GCL) and at least since Groovy 1.8 indirectly through GroovyScriptEngine (GSE). But GSE loads it through a GCL as well.

But what GRL does is to "locate" the scripts and return an URL to the location. What GCL does is use the URL returned by a GRL to get the source and compile it to create the class, which is then available for loading.

GRL is a backend for GCL. So they are not different ways to the same end. True, you still have to do more things to actually execute the script code (unless it is precompiled), but "get the script source, compile it, make a Class out of it and finally execute it" are the steps you always have to do. In our GRL/GCL discussion, GRL does part of the first step, GCL itself does the third step. Step 2 is done by CompilationUnit inside GCL and the last step is yours to be done. There are other ways to complete these steps of course, but that's out of the scope for this discussion.